# Custom error doesn't stop execution when R script is run from windows command prompt

Tags: r, windows, cmd

### Description

I'm working on some batch scripts that will execute some R scripts. I want to globally change how R errors are handled to make the errors display in color. In the process, I came across a very strange error. I used the `options()` command to change how errors are handled. What's strange is that the new error expressions stops further execution of the script as expected when the file is sourced in Rstudio, but the custom error **doesn't** stop execution when the script is called from command prompt.

I have the following R script:

#### Script 1

```r
# set global error options
options(error =function(){

  cat(" \033[97;101m There was an error! \033[0m\n")

})

# apples is undefined so it should return an error
print(apples)

# because the command above produces an error, this shouldn't print:
print("bananas")
```

When I source the script from within R the script stops executing at `print(apples)` as expected.

[image]

However when I try executing the script in windows command prompt using the R executable, the script doesn't stop executing at `print(apples)` like it should, instead it keeps going and executes `print("bananas")` too

[image]

I think it has something to do with the custom error, because when I change the R script to use the default error expression command prompt stops executing at `print(apples)` as expected. Here's the modified script:

#### Script 2

```r
# set global error options
options(error = NULL)

# apples is undefined so it should return an error
print(apples)

# because the command above produces an error, this shouldn't print:
print("bananas")
```

And here's the result:
[image]

### Questions

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I make sure that a custom error expression actually stops the R script's execution when executing the script from the command prompt?
3. Is there a better way to make R errors show up in color in the command prompt window? Maybe some windows equivalent to the `colorout` package?
4. If this is a bug, who's bug is it and any ideas on where to report it?

I don't want to use `trycatch` because I want to globally change the display color of all possible error messages not just specific blocks of code.  I'd like to be able to run these R scripts both from inside a batch script and also from within Rstudio without completely ending the R session on an error, just further execution of the script.

---

### Edit

After playing around with this further, I discovered that if I execute the **script 1** from command prompt in a different way, the script stops executing after encountering the first error.

```
"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "source('test_script.R')"
```

Leads to this result:
[image]

I have a workaround, (thank you r2evans!), but I am still really curious to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know why the behavior changes, we can reference https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html#dump.frames for the hint to `q`uit immediately with a non-zero exit status.

```r
options(error = function(){
  cat(" \033[97;101m There was an error! \033[0m\n")
  if (!interactive()) q(status = 1)
})
```

You may also choose to specify the other arguments `save=` and `runLast=`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It works well when running the script from command prompt, but it completely ends the R session when running the script from Rstudio. Ideally I'd like something that ends further execution of R commands without killing the R session similar to how the default R errors work. 

I'll add this to the question description, but I'd like to be able to run these R scripts both from inside a batch script and also from within Rstudio.

Comment: ahh, good point ... see my edit to add `!interactive()`, @Russ

Comment: Yay! That worked thank you so much!

Comment: That difference is just “how they work”.